# Question about line integrals with various options

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, line-integrals

I am new to calculus and am looking for some feedback regarding the following question. Many thanks in advance!

The following line integral is given:
$$\int_C(y + y \cos(xy))dx + (x + x \cos(xy))dy$$
Which of the following statements are correct?

$ 1.~$ If $C=(x-3)^2+(y-4)^2=1$, with clockwise movement, then the integral is $0$.

$ 2.~$ If C is circular arc $x^2+y^2=8$ from point $(2,2)$ to point $(-2,-2)$, then the integral is not $0$.

$3.~$ If $1 \le t \le\frac{π}{2}$ and $C=\mathbf C(t)=t\mathbf i+\frac{π}{t}\mathbf j$, then the integral is $0$.

My interpretation is the following:

I found the potential $φ: yx+\sin(xy)$, which means that the outcome of the integral will be independent of its path, and can be calculated via $φ(x_1,y_1)-φ(x_0,y_0)$.

This yields the following results:

$ 1.~$ always $0$
$ 2.~$ $0$
 $3.~$ not $0$, based on $φ(\frac{π}{2},2)-φ(1,π)$.

Thus $1$ is correct and $2$ and $3$ are incorrect.

Any comments will be very much appreciated!

Comment: i think you didnt put spaces the right way in your integral

Comment: for some reason it will not let me separate the expression any more than my edit...

Comment: sorry, i meant brackets not spaces haha

Comment: you were right!